# Would GET methods never be used with a secure OAuth/OpenClient based application?

Tags: rest

If I am writing a microservice that requires an access token to perform any operation, am I correct in saying that I would never design that service such that it would accept a GET request?  I say this since a GET request can't have a body, and in this case an access token must be passed in...which should be passed in a body.  So is it true that servers that are secured using access tokens would never implement GET methods?  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Most people pass access tokens in headers, not the body.

Comment: Well, that makes sense.